# Google docs importXML TripAdvisor

Tags: xml, xpath, google-sheets, google-docs, google-docs-api

ImportXML : I am trying to scrape http://www.tripadvisor.in/Hotels-g297615-c2-Gurgaon_Haryana-Hotels.html . I need the following fields - Name of the hotel, URL, Address, City, Pincode, no of reviews(just number) for each hotel, percentage and amenities. I want this all in a single row for a single hotel. Can anyone help me out.

Google Doc Link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1D6X9c9uX7AltxWQ3ln0Pqqzq_CIroCkDxPYr6lv-47k/edit#gid=1666841843

I  am unable to get all the above requirements in GoogleDoc. I am stuck in the address scraping just beside the URL.

Comment: I have extracted all the 263 hotel names and their respective URLs.

For extracting the address, i have used this code : =IMPORTXML(concatenate("http://www.tripadvisor.in",D2),"//span[@class='street-address']")

This is giving me same address twice for a cell(url). This is because there are two same address in the page that refers to the query given. Now i just want one address. How do i go about about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Responding to your comment, you can limit data returned by the xpath to one using index (`[1]`), for example (formatted for readability):

```
=IMPORTXML(concatenate("http://www.tripadvisor.in",D2),
            "(//span[@class='street-address'])[1]")
```

Comment: Updated question: I have extracted Hotel Names, URL, Address, Locality, Pincode, No of Reviews. Now i want to extract how many gave excellent, v.good, good, etc as their review out of the total number of reviews for specific hotel.

No i am using the code =IMPORTXML(concatenate("http://www.tripadvisor.in",D2),"//div/div/span[@class='compositeCount']") for the same. This is giving me the answer. But the answer appears in columns. I want them in rows. Please help

Comment: I don't understand the problem : "*This is giving me the answer. But the answer appears in columns. I want them in rows*" ??

Comment: when IMPORTXML() returns a column array you can flip it into a rwo by using TRANSPOSE() : `=transpose(IMPORTXML(concatenate("http://www.tripadvisor.in",D2),"(//div/div/span[@class='compositeCount'])"))`